# System.AccessViolationException thrown intermitently when closing secondary window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, exception

I am currently working with a Windows form application that opens a new window on a button click.  I intermittently get the following exception when I close the second window which in turns crashes my application.

> Application: Manager.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:
>   The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception
>   Info: System.AccessViolationException Stack:    at
>   System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods+Gdip.GdipDrawImageRectRectI(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32,
>   Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32,
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, DrawImageAbort,
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef)    at
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image,
>   System.Drawing.Rectangle, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32,
>   System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes,
>   DrawImageAbort, IntPtr)    at
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image,
>   System.Drawing.Rectangle, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32,
>   System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.DrawBackgroundImage(System.Drawing.Graphics,
>   System.Drawing.Image, System.Drawing.Color,
>   System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout, System.Drawing.Rectangle,
>   System.Drawing.Rectangle, System.Drawing.Point,
>   System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs,
>   System.Drawing.Rectangle, System.Drawing.Color, System.Drawing.Point) 
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs,
>   System.Drawing.Rectangle)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPaintBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnPaintBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs,
>   Int16)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmEraseBkgnd(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32,
>   IntPtr, IntPtr)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntBeginPaint(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef,
>   PAINTSTRUCT ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32,
>   IntPtr, IntPtr)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr,
>   Int32, Int32)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32,
>   System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32,
>   System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)    at
>   Manager.Program.Main()

I am usually able to open and close without any trouble during the day but if I leave the program running overnight and try to open the second window in the morning I will get this exception when I try to close the window.  This exception is getting thrown more often now then when I first started to run the application.

Has anybody seen this exception or know how to fix it?  I have searched extensively online to try to find an answer but have been unable to find one that is applicable.

Comment: Are you closing the window in the same way each time? For example, are you using the X in the corner sometimes, and code under a button other times?

Comment: Do you have any Closed or Closing event handlers for the form? Do you have any dynamically created controls or custom controls on the form?

Comment: I close the window different ways but teh exception occurs when I close it using the x in the corner and when I press the close button.

I have no closed or closing event handlers in the form relating to this window.  The second window that is being closed is a wpf window where as the main application is a windows form.  Could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with mixing winforms and WPF. I added the WPF tag so that hopefully someone with more knowledge on the subject can find this question.